# Cannot Deploy Windows Driver

Tags: visual-c++, driver, windbg

I'm trying to deploy a demo HelloWorld driver from Microsoft to a Windows10 VM on my machine. I've managed to establish the kernel debugger connection using "attach process" on the debug option and selecting the VM's kernel but whenever I try to deploy the actual driver I keep getting this error:

```
Could not connect to the remote computer for deployment
```

Now the fact that I can use WinDgb commands like `.reload` or `lm` and get a valid response suggests me that connection is fine but I don't know what's causing the problem. [image]

Comment: How did you attach the WinDbg to the VM Kernel? was it virtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deploying to Windows 10 then I suggest that you use Visual Studio 2017 project "Driver Package" -- you setup the project to connect to your target computer ( make sure that you have run WDK Test Target Setup x64-x64_en-us on the target computer )

When you then choose deploy on the Driver Package project then it should make all the necessary connections and transfer of your driver - its a bit slow but it works (well sometimes you must rebuild, some small bugs still there)

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can then verify that the driver is installed on the target computer by using
the tool WinObj.exe - look in Device and in GLOBAL??  - there you should find your driver - my drivers name was "serupITdevice123"

[image]